# Page not loading after proxy change using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am trying to change my proxy using selenium driver in python. But when I change it the page is not loading. I have tried several IPs but none worked. 
I also increased page timeout, but still was unable to access the site.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#ip address that I got from https://free-proxy-list.net/
ProxyHost = "110.34.39.58"
ProxyPort = "8080"

def ChangeProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    print
    PROXY_PORT
    print
    PROXY_HOST
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https", PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", int(PROXY_PORT)))
    fp.update_preferences()
    return  webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=
                 r'C:\webdriver\geckodriver.exe',firefox_profile=fp)

driver=ChangeProxy(ProxyHost, ProxyPort)
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need load a specific profile adding the path so

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profilePath)
```

Currently working for me specifying the profile path and the arguments:

```
("network.proxy.type", 3)
("network.proxy.http", "localhost")
("network.proxy.http_port", 5555)
```

Comment: I don't want to use localhost but a different proxy. How do I do that?